# What is this PC game in this youtube video?

Tags: game-identification

I would like your help to identify a game that was displayed in a comic video.

[Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/u7u0Ck2SUto?t=36)

The game that appears at the end of the video is FIFA 18. I would like to know the game that appear in the middle, at 36 seconds. It seems to be an Xbox game by the controller that the player is using and it looks like hack 'n' slash game or RPG.

[image: game image]

PS: this youtube channel has english subtitles, but the discussion that happens in the video is not related with the game.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The game in the video is definitly **Blade & Bones**.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QUR9hRA9eE), proves it, as the UI as well as the boss name match the video posted in the question.